Why even with anisotropy, we can still compute embedding similarity in (some RAG) projects
I have just noticed that the token/sentence embeddings trained from Transformer-based model will have strong anisotropy problem which means most of the embeddings are close to each other in the vector space.
So I am confused if those embeddings have such problem, why we can still calculate the embeddings similarity(like by cosine similarity) in some downstream cases? Like for a RAG project, usually we will compute the similarity of the input query with the vector database to select potential relevant chunks.
And why and how this anisotropy problem does not affect the performance of these token/sentence embeddings?
The first paper finds out Anisotropy

The link under "The first paper finds out Anisotropy" is broken. Without the source it is hard to get what kind of the problem you exactly address.

@DamirTenishev Sorry for the issue. I have changed the new URL and it should be fine now

I find that, like in the RAG project, when we first select relevant chunks from the vector database, the embedding similarity of the Bi-Encoder model should have some problems. But we can alleviate this problem by using the Reranker model, which theoretically will not suffer from this anisotropy problem because it treats the query block pair as the overall input of the model.

They key thing is that we always use the best we have now rather than hypothetical best we could have in future (or could have with significantly higher costs). The anisotropy here caused mostly not by algorithms, but by the language itself, so it is unavoidable. We have to live with it and find ways to handle is in “downstream cases” (in your terms).

Basic embedding algorithms like word2vec give us very good first guess values.
Then we use transfer learning with models like Transformers, BERT, etc. to improve the embeddings providing contextualized embeddings and domain adaptation.

Gradual improvement model is better because of nature of natural languages where most words are polysemous and their meaning depend strongly on the context.
You can have better embeddings, but the price would be quite high, it is simple to start with good enough guesses and improve when you have more context (in “downstream cases”).
This link (What exactly is meant by isotropic and anisotropic with word vectors)could be helpful, as well.
